# Codeigniter passing data from controller to view using the indicies as variables doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a simple codeigniter website after I already have had experience with it in the past. I have never set one up but I have worked an already existed codeigniter website.

My Controller looks like this:

```
<?php
class data_c extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('data_model');
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
            $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('data_v', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}
?>
```

and my view looks like this:

```
Welcome to the Data Page! <br>

<a href="home">Home Page</a> <br>
<a href="about">About Page</a> <br>
<a href="data_v">Data Page</a> <br>

<head>
        <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
</body>
```

And I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: heading

Filename: pages/data_v.php

Line Number: 11
```

From my understanding when you pass the $data array you refer to the elements of the array as the variable in the view. For example $data['test'] would be $test in the view.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That seems like it should work, check for spelling errors.

Comment: try load your `header` and `footer` inside your `data_v` file.